# What is Standard Referencing of Cryptography Papers

Tags: reference-request

I am writing a paper. One of my references is

> 1)Barreto, P. and Rijmen, V., “The Khazad Legacy-Level Block Cipher,” Submission 
>      to the NESSIE Project, vol. 97, 2004.

My professor criticize me that why I wrote *submission to the NESSIE Project* or why you did not write the journal of this paper or did not wrote the number of pages of this paper. What is its conference and where did it hold?

I searched in internet but most of all papers write this reference like $(1)$.

I am really confused and need help to write this kind of cryptography papers.

Really Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I failed to find what the "vol. 97, 2004" part of the question's citation refers to, or a formal journal or proceedings publication for that paper. It is much earlier (made public in November 2000).

The first author cites his paper (at line 38 in the *conference paper* section [here](https://directory.tacoma.uw.edu/sites/default/files/Paulo%20Barreto%20-%20Curriculum%20Vitae%20-%20Spring%202016_0.pdf)) as:

> BARRETO, P. S. L. M.;  Rijmen, V.; 2000: The KHAZAD Legacy-Level Block Cipher. In: 1st Open NESSIE Workshop, 2000, Leuven (Belgium). Proceedings of the 1st Open NESSIE Workshop.

The second author cites his paper (at line 235 [here](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/retrieve.php?author=vrijmen)) as:

> P. S. Barreto, and V. Rijmen, "The Khazad legacy-level block cipher," In Proceedings of the 1st NESSIE Workshop, 15 pages, 2000.

It also [has been](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2003/09_Session08/21_084/28940347.pdf#page=11) cited as

> P. Barreto and V. Rijmen. The Khazad Legacy-Level Block Cipher. In
>   First Open NESSIE Workshop, KU-Leuven, 2000. Submission to NESSIE.

If I had to cite this paper on this website, it could be as:

> Paulo S.L.M. Barreto and Vincent Rijmen, *The KHAZAD Legacy-Level Block Cipher*, submission to [First Open NESSIE Workshop, 13-14 November 2000, Leuven, Belgium](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/workshop/); file khazad/B/Khazad.pdf in [khazad.zip](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/workshop/submissions/khazad.zip).

---

The closest I found to 2004 is that Paulo Barreto cites (in the *Other publications* section [here](https://directory.tacoma.uw.edu/sites/default/files/Paulo%20Barreto%20-%20Curriculum%20Vitae%20-%20Spring%202016_0.pdf#page=10)) a different, shorter paper,

> V. Rijmen, BARRETO,  P. S. L. M., “The Khazad Block Cipher,”, *The Perl Journal* 7, p. 5, 2003.

It is online [here](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/TPJ/2003/0308/0308a/0308as1.htm) and was apparently an insert in [this](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/TPJ/2003/0308/0308a/0308a.htm).

---

Addition: if there was ever formal Proceedings of the 1st Open NESSIE Workshop, its current web presence is [this](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/workshop/). Here are the remains of a [Nessie Book](https://web.archive.org/web/20060901225704/http://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.ac.be:80/nessie/) planned circa 2004.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions completely. Is citation  of *The Anubis Block Cipher* is the same as the mentioned paper. thanks again